How to pass an access token from the login page to another page?
So I am using rest api as back end, I am unable to edit so I found that the token needs to be passed, from login to this change-profile api, so that the user can successfully edit his or her details .
Future<void> updateProfile() async {
  String url = "http:///myprofile/${userId}/";

  // Build the query parameters with updated user information
  Map<String, String> queryParams = {
    "email": _emailController.text,
    "password": passwordController.text,
    "repassword": repasswordController.text,
    "firstname": firstname.text,
    "lastname": lastname.text,
    "phonenumber": phonenumber.text,
    "state": state.text,
    "city": city.text,
    "Zip": zip.text,
    "mailing": _value.toString(),
    "referred_by": selectedItem,
    "flag": "business",
    "businessname": businesscontroller.text,
  };
  String queryString = Uri(queryParameters: queryParams).query;
  url += '?' + queryString;

  try {
    final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
      },
    );

    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print(url);
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Success
      _showSuccessDialog();
      // Navigate to the next page or perform any other actions
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BottomPage(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // Error
      _showErrorDialog('Failed to update profile. Please try again.');
    }

    print(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error updating profile: $e');
    _showErrorDialog('Failed to update profile. Please try again.');
  }
}

I attached the code snippet above of what I tried
I need to modify it in such a way that it can access the token from successful login which can help to edit information.

you can store the token in sharedpreferences and access it in the edit-profile screen.

This should help
    final token = "your-backend-token";

    final response = await http.put(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        HttpHeaders.authorization: token,
      },
    );

Additionally you could have something like this
class ApiHandler {
  ApiHandler.instance(); // for instantiating request withou token

  String? _token;

  ApiHandler.tokenInstance() {
    _token = getToken() ?? throw "No Token found";
    // `getToken()` gets token from shared preferences or wherever you have stored.
  }

  // use this for public api requests
  Map<String, String> get jsonHeaders = {
    HttpHeaders.contentType: "application/json",
  }

  // use this for authorized api requests
  Map<String, String> get tokenHeaders = {
    HttpHeaders.contentType: "application/json",
    HttpHeaders.authorization: _token,
  }

  // your other api request methods  
}


You need to use SharedPreferences package to store the token from successful login this:
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('token', '$<yourToken>');

then when you need to access a token just call:
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String? token = prefs.getString('token');


You can do this in 3 ways:

Create a global variable and store the token in there
Use SharedPreferences to permanently store the token
Pass the token as a parameter
3.1. Pass the token as a constructor parameter
3.2. Pass the token as a function parameter

1. Global variable
You can create a global file that contains this variable and import it wherever it will be accessed. This ensures that you have the same token as long as the application isn't restarted. After a restart, the variable will reset again
2. shared_preferences
Simarly you use the shared_preferences plugin by flutter.dev, you can store data permanently on every machine.
Thing to note: You will need to handle the async initialisation of SharedPreferences when you use this method. After it is initialised, the read calls aren't async
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

3. Pass the token as a parameter
3.1. Constructor parameter
This will be a bit of a hassle and I wouldn't recommend it for your use case, but it is still an option. Here's an example of how to do that with a StatefulWidget:
class ProfileOptions extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileOptions({super.key, required this.id});

  final String id;

  @override
  State<Product> createState() => _ProfileOptionsState();
}

class _ProfileOptionsState extends State<ProfileOptions> {
  late String id;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    id = widget.id;
  }}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Placeholder();
  }
}

3.2. Function parameter
You can also pass the token as a parameter of your function. This will require you to store and access the token at the place you are calling the function from (So you'd still need to do 1, 2, 3.1 or you need to store the function in the same file as the variable and then you can access the variable from within the function)
Future<void> updateProfile(String authToken) async {
  // Your code
}

